# Apache HTTP server failed to start - how to stop other servers from listening on ports?

Tags: raspbian, apache-httpd, raspbian-wheezy

While trying to host a website to control GPIO over flask and Apache I am now receiving the error that 'Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server'. Some googling suggested that this might happen if other servers are listening on port 80 so I did `sudo ss -ntlp 'sport = 80'` and returned two, both of which were lighttpd.

`sudo service apache2 restart` is what I executed when I first received this error; I was able to get the 'It Works!' page when I first instlled Apache.

How can I disable/turn off these servers using port 80?

Answer (score 2):

You can stop lighttpd if you run

```
sudo systemctl stop lighttpd
```

If you are sure to disable lighttpd (don't want to run it again).

```
sudo systemctl disable lighttpd
```